# how to index the sql database for using Match Against query

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin

I want to use Match Against query in my sql for the following geolocation query :-

```
SELECT location.lid, location_instance.uid, users.name
         , users.mail , location.latitude , location.longitude , users.picture, 
         ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS($lat) ) * COS( RADIANS( location.latitude ) ) 
         * COS( RADIANS( location.longitude ) - RADIANS($lon) ) + SIN( RADIANS($lat) ) 
         * SIN( RADIANS( location.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
            from {location} LEFT JOIN {location_instance} ON location.lid = location_instance.lid 
            LEFT JOIN {users} ON location_instance.uid = users.uid WHERE MATCH (users.name) 
            AGAINST ('$search_term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY distance
```

But i guess i would have to initially run an indexing query in my database. Please guide me nt much of a web guy

Edit :

The

Answer (score 0):

The sql to add full-text index :-

```
alter table users add fulltext index (name);
```

After adding the index :-

```
show index from users;
```

You should seeing something like :-

```
       Table: users
  Non_unique: 1
    Key_name: name
Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: name
   Collation: NULL
 Cardinality: ????
    Sub_part: NULL
      Packed: NULL
        Null: 
  Index_type: FULLTEXT
     Comment:
```